# Ejecución lenta por primera vez después de instalar la aplicación

Tags: android

La app tarda mucho en ejecutarse cuando se instala por primera vez. Parece que se queda "colgada".

Este es el estado de la pantalla en ese momento:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego pasado unos cuantos segundo (10 o 15), se inicia correctamente.

Cuando la app se queda colgada en el `logcat` se muestra la siguiente linea:

```
05-23 21:37:13.604 27661-27661/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo-1/lib/arm
```

Después este es el `logcat`completo:
Las etiquetas, `LogApp` y `DatabaseHelper` son mias para ir monitorizando la situación de la aplicación.

```
05-23 21:37:28.835 27661-27661/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo-1/lib/arm
05-23 21:37:28.939 27661-27661/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/GMPM: App measurement is starting up, version: 8487
05-23 21:37:28.939 27661-27661/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/GMPM: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.GMPM VERBOSE
05-23 21:37:29.248 27661-27661/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-23 21:37:29.522 27661-27661/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/LogApp: Main.java: Entrando en el onCreate de la app!
05-23 21:37:29.555 27661-27661/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/DatabaseHelper: LoadDb.Async.java: Entra en PreExecute
05-23 21:37:29.600 27661-28432/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/DatabaseHelper: LoadDb.Async.java: Entra en doInBackground
05-23 21:37:29.605 27661-28433/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
05-23 21:37:29.625 27661-27661/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/DatabaseHelper: LoadDb.Async.java: Entra en onProgressUpdate
05-23 21:37:29.647 27661-28432/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/LogApp: DatabaseHelper. createDataBase. BD cargada.
05-23 21:37:29.684 27661-28433/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
05-23 21:37:29.689 27661-28433/com.kirolm.kmibilbideaklezo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

Comment: He visto que usas un Asynctask sería buena idea que agregaras el código seguramente eso hace que tarde al iniciar...

Comment: El problema es de la opción `Instant Run`que proporciona Android Studio. Si se desabilita la app corre perfectamente con lo que deduzco que una ves subida a Google Play no habrá ningún problema. 

Para desabilitar `Instant Run` Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment.  Encontré la respuesta aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0.

(No sé como cerrar el post. Creo una pregunta y la selecciono como mejor respuesta?)

Comment: crea una respuesta y seleccionala como mejor respuesta! :) aunque sinceramente eso no tiene que ver con el código es con el uso de la IDE, si usas Instant Run  tu aplicación no va a tardar ya que no va a realizar un  build de todo el proyecto.

Comment: Eso es. No tiene que ver con el código pero cuando puse la pregunta no lo sabía. Efectivamente con Instant Run la app tarda mucho menos en ejecutarse pero la primera vez es donde se ralentiza. Después va realmente rápido gracias a esta característica de IDE.

Comment: Aún así sería bueno agregaras tu respuesta y la marques como solucionada para que otros desarrolladores la vean! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es de la opción `Instant Run` que proporciona Android Studio. Si se desabilita la app corre perfectamente con lo que deduzco que una ves subida a Google Play no habrá ningún problema.

Para desabilitar `Instant Run`:

Android Studio -> Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run y desmarcar `Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled)`. Encontré la respuesta aquí:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623917/first-launch-take-long-time-in-android-studio-2-0-gradle-2-0

De todas formas, sabiendo que es causa del IDE Android Studio se puede seguir con la opción `Instant Run` habilitada, ya que una vez publicada en Google Play la app se ejecutará rápido.

Comment: Además puedes implementar un splashscreen, porque normalmente la primera vez que se ejecuta la app tarda un poco más.

Comment: Es correcto, crear la base de datos por primera vez se toma su tiempo; dependiendo de la estructura de la misma.